# How to get distinct xp values?

Tags: ordercloud

Each product has two xp parameters - productLine, productType.
Under productLine, there are multiple product types. 
I need to fetch list of distinct productType under each productLine. 
There is limit on listing all products due to pagination. 
Is it possible with ordercloud?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for here. Do you want to get a list of all products where there is a value set for xp.productline? Or are you just trying to get a list of all the productType options, for something like displaying them/etc?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is there's no shortcut way to do this. Typically in these scenarios it works the other way - you have a pre-defined list of possible values and restrict what goes in via a dropdown list in the UI, or an enum in the integration layer, or something along those lines. For your scenario, you would need to resort to fetching all products (page by page) and keeping track of those unique values. Ideally that one be a one-time thing and going forward I'd suggest validating/restricting the input, although I don't know your exact requirements.